# JavaScript select() method

Tags: javascript

What does the `select()` method in JavaScript do? When should we use it?

Comment: Which select() method do you mean exactly? Why not look in the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** .select() is a jQuery function.

This method is a shortcut for `.bind('select', handler)` in the first two variations, and `.trigger('select')` in the third.

The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes.

Comment: This is jQuery, though. The OP is not mentioning jQuery (although it's possible it's what he means)

Comment: It can also be used on a DOM element, where it means 'select all contents'.